# Create new table with some columns that starts with from old table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table say 'A' which have bunch of columns but some columns that begin with DM_ (eg. DM_T, DM_3...).

How do I create another table B with all these columns that begin with DM_ and data? I am looking for some dynamic option like following which doesn't work

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + column_name   
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'A'  AND column_name LIKE 'DM_%'

SELECT @Names INTO B
FROM A
```

Comment: use [**sp_excutesql**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 2):

You need dynamic SQL for that:

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000);

-- this may be tricky especially when ORDER BY is involved
SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + column_name   
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'A'  AND column_name LIKE 'DM_%';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT <cols> INTO B FROM A';
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '<cols>', @Names);

PRINT @sql;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4f1b0bacfd3e1e251e39bda992bec2eb)**

Answer (score 0):

While I am certain there are dozens of ways to accomplish this, you could try using a CTE for this interaction.

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) 

;WITH MyNames (Names) AS (
    SELECT COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + column_name   
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_name = 'A'  AND column_name LIKE 'DM_%'
)

SELECT * 
FROM MyNames
```